# Why when using Time.timeScale to make a slowdown effect it's changing the resolution to full screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to empty GameObject :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SlowDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0,0.25f)]
    public float isTime = 0.25f;

    private void Update()
    {
        Time.timeScale = isTime;
    }
}
```

Once running the game it's slowing down but also make it a full screen :

[image: Full screen while slow down effect]

Comment: The script doesn't do it but the button "Maximize on Play" in the upper right corner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It isn't. You have this button toggled on:

[image: Maximize on play button]